# Is there an Interface to Run Selenium 2.0 WebDriver Test Cases other than NUnit?

Tags: selenium2, webdriver, gui, nunit

Is it possible to wrap around Selenium 2.0 WebDriver Test Cases with anything other than NUnit for C# code?  Or perhaps NUnit has a nice application to do this with?  If not, how can I wrap around the code.  I would like to create a web interface that displays the results of our test cases and logs information about successes/failures of each test case.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to wrap around Selenium 2.0 WebDriver Test Cases with
>   anything other than NUnit for C# code?

Yes. Extending the user246’s answer, Selenium is just a library that allows you to manipulate with web pages.  Unit Test Framework wraps your tests and helps you to run the  tests and produce the test execution report with number of passed/failed tests. You can also use MS Test, NUnit, xUnit or any other test framework.

> Or perhaps NUnit has a nice application to do this with? If not, how
>   can I wrap around the code

Yes, NUnit is good for this as any other unit test framework. Any popular test framework produces the test execution results as the XML file. From this XML file you could generate any HTML/PDF report you want.

> I would like to create a web interface that displays the results of
>   our test cases and logs information about successes/failures of each
>   test case. How can this be done?

There are several open source and/or free  tools that can schedule tests and produce online report.
Please consider Jenkins or TeamCity or any other Continious Integration server. 
But, it will be much easier if you start from generating offline HTML report and just send it by email.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is just an API.  You should be able to use it with any C# test framework.

Answer (score 2):

Typically people hook a continuous integration server up with selenium to provide a web interface. You can use Jenkins, it's open source, and can allow you to execute tests remotely, track success/failures, etc.

Also try MbUnit/Gallio instead of nUnit, it provides a much more robust package to perform typical testing tasks, and includes better reporting and metrics.

Comment: our company uses Cruise Control for continuous integration.  I'll have to look into this.  Ideally we'd like to be able to kick our scripts off when people commit code to tell them right away whether they broke something.